# How can I get the same equation when using feedback loop analysis?

Tags: feedback

This is the circuit:

[image]

Formula correction according to  @Puk. (Shout out to Puk!)

$$V_{in} g_{m1} + \frac{V_{o}} {r_{o1}} = (V_{in} - V_o) s C - \frac{V_o} {r_{o2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_o} {V_{in}} = \frac{g_{m1} - s C} {s C + 1/r_{o2} + 1/r_{o2}}$$

For analysis in feedback loop.

Open loop DC gain:

$$V_{in} g_{m1} + \frac{V_{o}} {r_{o1}} =  \frac{V_o} {r_{o2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_o} {V_{in}} = - g_{m1} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o2})$$

\$\beta\$ for this feedback network.

$$\beta = -s C $$

$$A_{v,close} = \frac{- g_{m1} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o2}) } {1 + s C  g_{m1} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o2})}$$

\$\mbox{$\Large \frac{- g_{m1} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o2}) } {1 + s C  g_{m1} (r_{o1} \parallel r_{o2})} $}\$ and \$\frac{g_{m1} - s C} {s C + 1/r_{o2} + 1/r_{o2}}\$ are different!

Comment: Is there any feedback? I think, there is no feedback voltage at all - due to the ideal voltage source Vin1. The only influence of Cf1 on the gain is due to the Miller effect.

Comment: @LvW input and output are connected together with a capacitor so there is feedback

Comment: I agree with LvW. There is no feedback because the input signal is a voltage source and that defines the gate-source voltage of M1 irrespective of the value of Cf.

Comment: To make it clear (with other words): Any feedback signal will be shorted by the voltage source (zero source resistance).